# Zurb Foundation data-abide / data-equalto not working in asp.net, validation errors display on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, zurb-foundation

I'm just trying to do a simple password confirmation validation using data-abide and data-equalto and I just can't figure out what's wrong.  The validation errors show beneath the text boxes on page load and do not go away no matter what I type in the boxes.

```
<form ID="form1" runat="server" data_abide="">
    <div class="row">
        <fieldset class="panel">
            <legend>Email Address</legend>
            <div class="small-4 columns">
                <label>Email Address <small>required</small></label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="emailAddress" runat="server" placeholder="Email" required=""></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="password-field">
                <div class="small-4 columns">
                    <label>Applicant Password <small>required</small></label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" placeholder="Password" TextMode="password" required=""></asp:TextBox> <small class="error">You must enter an application password.</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="password-confirmation-field">
                <div class="small-4 columns">
                    <label>Confirm Password <small>required</small></label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="confirmPassword" runat="server" placeholder="Confirm Password" TextMode="password" data_equalto="password" required=""></asp:TextBox> <small class="error">Password does not match.</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue (worked in Chrome, but not in Firefox or Safari). After some trial and error I discovered that if the id of the first password field is "password" then it will throw a mismatch. I changed my first password's attribute from **id="password"** to **id="checkpassword"** and it fixed the mismatch problem.

Hopefully your issue is similar.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since the question was asked so perhaps you moved on...

In the form tag, should it be data-abide instead of data_abide  ??